# How to Know an Alert Pop-Up Has Occurred

Tags: excel, vba, selenium

I am automating a website. I am using SeleniumBasic in Excel VBA.

I have a simple Pop-Up, or Alert, with an OK button.
[image]

I cannot access the Pop_Up by using Inspect so I have no HTML to show.

When the Pop-Up occurs, I respond with `Driver.SwitchToAlert.Accept`. It goes away, as desired.

I don't know how to check programmatically if the Pop-Up is present.
If I assume that the Pop-Up may have occurred and use this code on a just-in-case basis, i.e. use the code without the Pop-Up existing, the program stops without any error message.

Is there a way to check if the Pop-Up window exists before I respond?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the answer:
I got this code from someone who got it from someone else.

```
Private Function AlertIsPresent() As Boolean
    'Returns true if an alert is present, false otherwise
    Dim T As String
    On Error Resume Next
    T = Driver.Title 'This raises error 26 if an alert(pop-up) is displayed                           
    AlertIsPresent = (26 = Err.Number)
End Function
```

If function returns 'true', use the `Driver.SwitchToAlert.Accept` to close it.